# "Времяпровождение" или "времяпрепровождение"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Как правильно: "времяпровождение" или "времяпрепровождение"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- В "Большом толковом словаре русского языка" под ред. С. А. Кузнецова (СПб.: Норинт, 1998) есть оба слова: и времяпрепровождение, и времяпровождение, — однако *времяпровождение* считается разговорным.
- В "Полном орфографическом словаре русского языка" под ред. В. В. Лопатина также оба слова в наличии. *(Нужно обратить внимание, что в орфографическом словаре не приводится стилистических рекомендаций.)*
- В "Толково-словообразовательном [словаре](http://www.efremova.info/) русского языка" Т. Ф. Ефремовой (2000) написано:  "Времяпровождение (разг.) — то же, что времяпрепровождение".

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего смысловой оттенок этих слов разнится в том, что, говоря о ПРИЯТНОМ или ПРАЗДНОМ проведении времени (например, приятное посещение чего-либо, приятная встреча с кем-либо...), мы используем ВРЕМЯПРЕПРОВОЖДЕНИЕ, а если о нейтральном или немного негативном (пустое, трудное..) - то скорее ВРЕМЯПРОВОЖДЕНИЕ.